# How to set data in HTML local storage using Python?

Tags: javascript, python

I want to set data in HTML local storage using Python (I am using Flask framework).
Do I need to use JavaScript?

Comment: Go through this link http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: I have already gone this tutorial, Now I know how to set data from java script. I want to do it from python.

Comment: Just to make sure you understand.... the python part runs on the server and generates the HTML view for the client to display. It doesn't run on the client at all. How do you expect the server-side python code to do this on the client?

Answer (score 5):

You need to use JavaScript.

Python (server-side) knows nothing about JavaScript (client-side) where localStorage resides.

The easiest, however many times not the most efficient, way to approach the problem is

- You have a JavaScript JS snippet running in your HTML page
- This JS makes an AJAX request to the server-side Flask view. Try [jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)
- Flask view returns JSON data
- JS code receives the JSON and stores it in the localStorage

Alternative, if the amount of data is few bytes, you can pass it from the server-side to the client-side (JavaScript) using cookies.